# Difference of different synonyms of 'beacuse'

Tags: synonyms

[image: Picture of the problem of different synonyms of 'because'.]I'm confused with different synonyms of 'because'.
What actually are the meanings and usages of the following synonyms of 'because'?

1. Due to
2. On account of
3. For
4. Because of, and
5. Owing to.
   I'm confused with the question in the picture attached with this question.

Comment: beacuse -> because ? :-) // We have in Czech very close equivalent of the last sentence, with loose meaning ironically "Mr. Hasan can thank the incident that the coming later happened."

Comment: Of course _form_ should read _from_, so I don't know whether _come_ in (a)  is a deliberate mistake.  (C) is wrong because _to be late for something_ has a different meaning., and (d) should be _met with an accident_. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10325/what-is-the-difference-between-owing-to-and-due-to#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20difference%20between,result%20or%20consequence%20of%20something.) includes a long discussion of the differences between _due to_ and _owing to_!

Comment: When I Google the exercise, I see that several versions change the question to **from** and answer *a* to **came**.

Comment: What is the source of the image? It is full of mistakes to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these make sense. It should be

> Mr. Hasan was late because of an accident.

or

> Mr. Hasan was late due to an accident.

or

> Mr. Hasan was late on account of an accident.

or

> Mr. Hasan was late owing to an accident.

They all mean the same thing.